# Retrieving a list of media in umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm just starting to play with the XSLT system in umbraco where I was hoping to produce a macro which listed all the media under a specific media directory.  I have come across umbraco.library:GetMedia but, frankly, I have no idea what to pass to it in order to get a list of items.  The API docs at http://umbraco.org/apiDocs/html/M_umbraco_library_GetMedia.htm seem to suggest that what I probably want is to look up a node (how?) and then pass it in with

```
umbraco.library:GetMedia(<some node id>, true)
```

How would I go about getting that initial node id?

Subsequently would something like this work?

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(<SOMEMAGIC>, 'true')">
    <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some great help from the folks over at in the umbraco forums I figured it out.  The thread is [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/4199-Retrieving-a-list-of-media) and the solution is basically this XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/data [@alias='mediaDir'], 'true')/node">
 <li>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="umbraco.library:GetMedia(@id, 'false')/data [@alias = 'umbracoFile']">
    <a><xsl:attribute name="href">
     <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetMedia(@id, 'false')/data [@alias = 'umbracoFile']"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--Do something with the directory-->
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

coupled with a media picker control on the page.

Comment: This does not work anymore for umbraco 4.5 and up.
http://www.notas-terrible.net/blog/post/Umbraco-45-XML-Schema-changed.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same code but updated to work with Umbraco 4.5 or later:

```
<xsl:variable name="images" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/mediaDir, 1)" />

<xsl:for-each select="$images/*">
 <li>
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="string(local-name()) = 'Image'">
       <a>
         <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="./umbracoFile"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
       </a>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--Do something with the directory-->
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```